# Terminal ESC Sequence Decoder

Tags: c++, parsing, console, boost

The goal of this code is to read-in a stream of terminal ESC sequences, and break them down and fill a vector of parameterized sequences for processing later on.

For example `ESC[5C`  would be filled in the vector as:

```
Vector[0] = C    
Vector[1] = 5
```

Colors for example `ESC[0;44;32m`

```
Vector[0] = m
Vector[1] = 0
Vector[2] = 44
Vector[3] = 32
```

This way I can always check vector [0] for the control character, then the following for it's separated parameters.

Most of the Xterm sequences are not yet supported, but their sequences are noted in the case statements for later implementation.

I use a state machine with processing levels to move along each sequences
each level should move to the next expected control character.

Just looking for some general feedback on design or if anyone notices any issues or oversights on my part.

**sequence_decoder.hpp**

```
#ifndef SequenceParser_H
#define SequenceParser_H

#include "safe_queue.hpp"
#include "message_queue.hpp"

#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Forward Deceleration
class Session;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Session> session_ptr;
typedef boost::weak_ptr<Session> session_weak_ptr;

/**
 * @class SequenceDecoder
 * @author Michael Griffin
 * @date 12/20/2015
 * @file sequence_decoder.hpp
 * @brief Processes incoming data into a message queue.
 */
class SequenceDecoder
{
public:

    SequenceDecoder(session_ptr session);
    ~SequenceDecoder();

    /**
     * @brief Queue the Pasred Data back to the Session for Display
     * @return
     */
    bool sessionQueue();

    // {Main Execution Method}
    // Validate and Decode ESC Sequences
    void decodeEscSequenceData(std::string &input_string);

private:

    // Handle to Session for Sending Responses to Client.
    session_weak_ptr  m_weak_session;

    // Holds Individual Sequences
    MessageQueue      m_message_queue;

    // Sequence Parser State
    enum
    {
        SEQ_NORMAL     = 0, // Normal Text Data
        SEQ_START      = 1, // Start of ESC Sequence
        SEQ_PROCESSING = 2, // Processing for Complete Sequence
        SEQ_DONE       = 3, // ESC Sequence Completed OK.
        SEQ_ERROR      = 4  // Bad Sequence, Kill it!
    };

    int unsigned  m_sequence_state;
    unsigned char m_sequence;
    int           m_parameter;
    bool          m_is_sequence;
    bool          m_is_parameter;
    bool          m_is_invalid_sequence;
    bool          m_is_sequence_completed;
    int           m_sequence_level;

    // Holds the intern data while we build the sequence,
    // This is needed if inputString doesn't have a complete sequence
    // Then we need to append so that the string will have the
    // Original first half of the already parsed sequence.
    std::string            m_sequence_builder;

    //Holds the breakdown of the entire sequence
    std::vector<int>       m_sequence_params;

    // This string contains normal data passed through the sequence
    // Parser, At the end of a processing loop, this data is passed
    // for writing to the screen.
    std::string            m_valid_output_data;
    std::string::size_type m_escape_position;

    /**
     * @brief Level 0 Parsing check for Start of CSI or Alternate ESC Sequences
     */
    void processSequenceLevel0();

    /**
     * @brief Level 1 Parsing Comes After ESC[ = CSI.
     * Numbers and Separators are found in the middle of sequences as Parameters
     * Switch Statement catch the end of a Valid Sequence.
     *
     * Any non-supported sequences can have certain characters after the CSI
     * and These are parsed so that they are skipped and marked Invalid.
     */
    void processSequenceLevel1();

    /**
     * @brief Level 2 Parsing Catches (2) Different Sequence Styles and Comes After ESC[ = CSI.
     * Specifically for ? preceding sequencing, and ' ' Space D ending Sequence
     * For syncterm font switching.
     *
     * Numbers and Separators are found in the middle of sequences as Parameters
     * Switch Statement catch the end of a Valid Sequence.
     *
     * Any non-supported sequences can have certain characters after the CSI
     * and These are parsed so that they are skipped and marked Invalid.
     */
    void processSequenceLevel2();

    /**
     * @brief Decode and Validate Escapce Sequences.
     */
    void validateSequence();

public:
    /**
     * @brief Reset the Sequence Parser to refresh the screen
     */
    void resetParser();

};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<SequenceDecoder> sequence_decoder_ptr;

#endif
```

**sequence_decoder.cpp**

```
#include "sequence_decoder.hpp"
#include "session.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

// Initialize Class Variables
SequenceDecoder::SequenceDecoder(session_ptr session)
    : m_weak_session(session)
    , m_sequence_state(SEQ_NORMAL)
    , m_sequence(0)
    , m_parameter(0)
    , m_is_sequence(false)
    , m_is_parameter(false)
    , m_is_invalid_sequence(false)
    , m_is_sequence_completed(false)
    , m_sequence_level(0)
{
    std::cout << "SequenceDecoder Created" << std::endl;
}

SequenceDecoder::~SequenceDecoder()
{
    std::cout << "~SequenceDecoder" << std::endl;
    std::vector<int>().swap(m_sequence_params);   // Clear Parameters
    m_message_queue.clear();                      // Clear Message Structure
}

/**
 * @brief Level 0 Parsing check for Start of CSI or Alternate ESC Sequences
 */
void SequenceDecoder::processSequenceLevel0()
{
    switch(m_sequence)
    {
        case '[': // Control Sequence Introduction ( CSI is 0x9b).
            break;

            // Xterm Sequences Not implemented, pass through
        case ' ':
            //ESC SP F 7-bit controls (S7C1T).
            //ESC SP G 8-bit controls (S8C1T).
            //ESC SP L Set ANSI conformance level 1 (dpANS X3.134.1).
            //ESC SP M Set ANSI conformance level 2 (dpANS X3.134.1).
            //ESC SP N Set ANSI conformance level 3 (dpANS X3.134.1).
        case '#':
            //ESC # 3 DEC double-height line, top half (DECDHL).
            //ESC # 4 DEC double-height line, bottom half (DECDHL).
            //ESC # 5 DEC single-width line (DECSWL).
            //ESC # 6 DEC double-width line (DECDWL).
            //ESC # 8 DEC Screen Alignment Test (DECALN).
        case '%':
            //ESC % @ Select default character set. That is ISO 8859-1 (ISO 2022).
            //ESC % G Select UTF-8 character set (ISO 2022).
        case '(':
            //ESC ( C
            //C = U ? CP437 Character Set. (Not shown on most! MF)
            //C = 0 ? DEC Special Character and Line Drawing Set.
            //C = < ? DEC Supplementary (VT200).
            //C = % 5 ? DEC Supplementary Graphics (VT300).
            //C = > ? DEC Technical (VT300).
            //C = A ? United Kingdom (UK).
            //C = B ? United States (USASCII).
            //C = 4 ? Dutch.
            //C = C or 5 ? Finnish.
            //C = R or f ? French.
            //C = Q or 9 ? French Canadian (VT200, VT300).
            //C = K ? German.
            //C = Y ? Italian.
            //C = ` , E or 6 ? Norwegian/Danish.
            //C = % 6 ? Portuguese (VT300).
            //C = Z ? Spanish.
            //C = H or 7 ? Swedish.
            //C = = ? Swiss.
        case ')':
            //Designate G1 Character Set (ISO 2022, VT100).
            //The same character sets apply as for ESC ( C.
        case '?':
            // Set/Reset Modes
            // Invalid, should have CSI = ESC[ preceding ?

            // Xterm C1 (8-Bit) Control Characters
        case 'D':  // Index ( IND is 0x84).
        case 'E':  // Next Line ( NEL is 0x85).
        case 'H':  // Tab Set ( HTS is 0x88).
        case 'M':  // Reverse Index ( RI is 0x8d).
        case 'N':  // Single Shift Select of G2 Character Set ( SS2 is 0x8e). This affects next character only.
        case 'O':  // Single Shift Select of G3 Character Set ( SS3 is 0x8f). This affects next character only.
        case 'P':  // Device Control String ( DCS is 0x90).
        case 'V':  // Start of Guarded Area ( SPA is 0x96).
        case 'W':  // End of Guarded Area ( EPA is 0x97).
        case 'X':  // Start of String ( SOS is 0x98).
        case 'Z':  // Return Terminal ID (DECID is 0x9a). Obsolete form of CSI c (DA).
        case ']':  // Operating System Command ( OSC is 0x9d).
        case '^':  // Privacy Message ( PM is 0x9e).
        case '_':  // Application Program Command ( APC is 0x9f).
        case '\\': // String Terminator ( ST is 0x9c).
        case '*':
            //ESC * C Designate G2 Character Set (ISO 2022, VT220).
            //The same character sets apply as for ESC ( C.
        case '+':
            //ESC + C Designate G3 Character Set (ISO 2022, VT220).
            //The same character sets apply as for ESC ( C.
        case '-':
            //ESC - C Designate G1 Character Set (VT300).
            //The same character sets apply as for ESC ( C.
        case '.':
            //ESC . C Designate G2 Character Set (VT300).
            //The same character sets apply as for ESC ( C.
        case '/':
            //ESC / C Designate G3 Character Set (VT300).
            //These work for 96-character sets only.
            //C = A ? ISO Latin-1 Supplemental.
        case '6':  // ESC 6 Back Index (DECBI), VT420 and up.
        case '7':  // ESC 7 Save Cursor (DECSC).
        case '8':  // ESC 8 Restore Cursor (DECRC).
        case '9':  // ESC 9 Forward Index (DECFI), VT420 and up.
        case '=':  // ESC = Application Keypad (DECKPAM).
        case '>':  // ESC > Normal Keypad (DECKPNM).
        case 'F':  // ESC F Cursor to lower left corner of screen. This is enabled by the hpLowerleftBugCompat resource.
        case 'c':  // ESC c Full Reset (RIS).
        case 'l':  // ESC l Memory Lock (per HP terminals). Locks memory above the cursor.
        case 'm':  // ESC m Memory Unlock (per HP terminals).
        case 'n':  // ESC n Invoke the G2 Character Set as GL (LS2).
        case 'o':  // ESC o Invoke the G3 Character Set as GL (LS3).
        case '|':  // ESC | Invoke the G3 Character Set as GR (LS3R).
        case '}':  // ESC } Invoke the G2 Character Set as GR (LS2R).
        case '~':  // ESC ~ Invoke the G1 Character Set as GR (LS1R).
        case '\0':   // Catch any NULL characters after ESC
        case '\x1b': // catch any double ESC's from bad servers
            m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
            break;

        default:
            // Nothing Matched, Shouldn't get here.
            m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Level 1 Parsing Comes After ESC[ = CSI.
 * Numbers and Separators are found in the middle of sequences as Parameters
 * Switch Statement catch the end of a Valid Sequence.
 *
 * Any non-supported sequences can have certain characters after the CSI
 * and These are parsed so that they are skipped and marked Invalid.
 */
void SequenceDecoder::processSequenceLevel1()
{
    // If we get here, only valid Sequences are ESC [ Then next Character.
    // First Check for Parameters in Sequence
    if(std::isdigit(m_sequence))  // Mark for Parameter
    {
        // Continue to next sequence
        return;
    }
    else if(m_sequence == ';') // Mark for Multi-Parameter
    {
        // Continue to Next Sequence
        return;
    }

    // Catch Valid ESC Sequence Terminators.
    switch(m_sequence)
    {
        case '@': // Insert P s (Blank) Character(s) (default = 1) (ICH).
        case 'A': // Cursor Up P s Times (default = 1) (CUU)
        case 'B': // Cursor Down P s Times (default = 1) (CUD)
        case 'C': // Cursor Forward P s Times (default = 1) (CUF)
        case 'D': // Cursor Backward P s Times (default = 1) (CUB)

        case 'E': // Cursor Next Line P s Times (default = 1) (CNL)
        case 'F': // Cursor Preceding Line P s Times (default = 1) (CPL)
        case 'G': // Cursor Character Absolute [column] (default = [row,1]) (CHA)
        case 'H': // Cursor Position [row;column] (default = [1,1]) (CUP)

        case 'I': // Cursor Forward Tabulation P s tab stops (default = 1) (CHT).
        case 'J':
            // Erase in Display (ED). - DECSED has ESC[?J
            //P s = 0 ? Erase Below (default).
            //P s = 1 ? Erase Above.
            //P s = 2 ? Erase All.
            //P s = 3 ? Erase Saved Lines (xterm).
        case 'K':
            // Erase in Line (EL). - DECSED has ESC[?K
            //P s = 0 ? Erase to Right (default).
            //P s = 1 ? Erase to Left.
            //P s = 2 ? Erase All.
        case 'L': // Insert P s Line(s) (default = 1) (IL).
        case 'M': // Delete P s Line(s) (default = 1) (DL).
        case 'P': // Delete P s Character(s) (default = 1) (DCH).
        case 'S': // Scroll up P s lines (default = 1) (SU).
        case 'T': // Scroll down P s lines (default = 1) (SD).
        case 'X': // Erase P s Character(s) (default = 1) (ECH).
        case 'Z': // Cursor Backward Tabulation P s tab stops (default = 1) (CBT).

        case '`': // Character Position Absolute [column] (default = [row,1]) (HPA).
        case 'a': // Character Position Relative [columns] (default = [row,col+1]) (HPR).
        case 'b': // Repeat the preceding graphic character P s times (REP).
        case 'c':
            // Send Device Attributes (Primary DA).
            //P s = 0 or omitted ? request attributes from terminal. The response depends on the decTerminalID resource setting.
            //?  CSI ? 1 ; 2 c (‘‘VT100 with Advanced Video Option’’)
            //?  CSI ? 1 ; 0 c (‘‘VT101 with No Options’’)
            //?  CSI ? 6 c (‘‘VT102’’)
            //?  CSI ? 6 2 ; P s c (‘‘VT220’’)
            //?  CSI ? 6 3 ; P s c (‘‘VT320’’)
            //?  CSI ? 6 4 ; P s c (‘‘VT420’’)
            // The VT100-style response parameters do not mean anything by themselves. VT220 (and higher) parameters do, telling the host what features the terminal supports:
            //P s = 1 ? 132-columns.
            //P s = 2 ? Printer.
            //P s = 3 ? ReGIS graphics.
            //P s = 4 ? Sixel graphics.
            //P s = 6 ? Selective erase.
            //P s = 8 ? User-defined keys.
            //P s = 9 ? National Replacement Character sets.
            //P s = 1 5 ? Technical characters.
            //P s = 1 8 ? User windows.
            //P s = 2 1 ? Horizontal scrolling.
            //P s = 2 2 ? ANSI color, e.g., VT525.
            //P s = 2 9 ? ANSI text locator (i.e., DEC Locator mode).
        case 'd': // Line Position Absolute [row] (default = [1,column]) (VPA).
        case 'e': // Line Position Relative [rows] (default = [row+1,column]) (VPR).
        case 'f': // equivalent to 'H'
        case 'g': // Tab Clear (TBC).
        case 'h':
            // Set Mode (SM).
            //P s = 2 ? Keyboard Action Mode (AM).
            //P s = 4 ? Insert Mode (IRM).
            //P s = 1 2 ? Send/receive (SRM).
            //P s = 2 0 ? Automatic Newline (LNM).

            // DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET). ESC [ ? h
            //P s = 1 ? Application Cursor Keys (DECCKM).
            //P s = 2 ? Designate USASCII for character sets G0-G3 (DECANM), and set VT100 mode.
            //P s = 3 ? 132 Column Mode (DECCOLM).
            //P s = 4 ? Smooth (Slow) Scroll (DECSCLM).
            //P s = 5 ? Reverse Video (DECSCNM).
            //P s = 6 ? Origin Mode (DECOM).
            //P s = 7 ? Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).
            //P s = 8 ? Auto-repeat Keys (DECARM).
            //P s = 9 ? Send Mouse X & Y on button press. See the section Mouse Tracking. This is the X10 xterm mouse protocol.
            //P s = 1 0 ? Show toolbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 2 ? Start Blinking Cursor (att610).
            //P s = 1 8 ? Print form feed (DECPFF).
            //P s = 1 9 ? Set print extent to full screen (DECPEX).
            //P s = 2 5 ? Show Cursor (DECTCEM).
            //P s = 3 0 ? Show scrollbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 3 5 ? Enable font-shifting functions (rxvt).
            //P s = 3 8 ? Enter Tektronix Mode (DECTEK).
            //P s = 4 0 ? Allow 80 ? 132 Mode.
            //P s = 4 1 ? more(1) fix (see curses resource).
            //P s = 4 2 ? Enable National Replacement Character sets (DECNRCM).
            //P s = 4 4 ? Turn On Margin Bell.
            //P s = 4 5 ? Reverse-wraparound Mode.
            //P s = 4 6 ? Start Logging. This is normally disabled by a compile-time option.
            //P s = 4 7 ? Use Alternate Screen Buffer. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 6 6 ? Application keypad (DECNKM).
            //P s = 6 7 ? Backarrow key sends backspace (DECBKM).
            //P s = 6 9 ? Enable left and right margin mode (DECLRMM), VT420 and up.
            //P s = 9 5 ? Do not clear screen when DECCOLM is set/reset (DECNCSM), VT510 and up.
            //P s = 1 0 0 0 ? Send Mouse X & Y on button press and release. See the section Mouse Tracking. This is the X11 xterm mouse protocol.
            //P s = 1 0 0 1 ? Use Hilite Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 2 ? Use Cell Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 3 ? Use All Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 4 ? Send FocusIn/FocusOut events.
            //P s = 1 0 0 5 ? Enable UTF-8 Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 6 ? Enable SGR Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 7 ? Enable Alternate Scroll Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 1 0 ? Scroll to bottom on tty output (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 1 ? Scroll to bottom on key press (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 5 ? Enable urxvt Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 3 4 ? Interpret "meta" key, sets eighth bit. (enables the eightBitInput resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 5 ? Enable special modifiers for Alt and NumLock keys. (This enables the numLock resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 6 ? Send ESC when Meta modifies a key. (This enables the metaSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 7 ? Send DEL from the editing-keypad Delete key.
            //P s = 1 0 3 9 ? Send ESC when Alt modifies a key. (This enables the altSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 0 ? Keep selection even if not highlighted. (This enables the keepSelection resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 1 ? Use the CLIPBOARD selection. (This enables the selectToClipboard resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 2 ? Enable Urgency window manager hint when Control-G is received. (This enables the bellIsUrgent resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 3 ? Enable raising of the window when Control-G is received. (enables the popOnBell resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 7 ? Use Alternate Screen Buffer. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 8 ? Save cursor as in DECSC. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 9 ? Save cursor as in DECSC and use Alternate Screen Buffer, clearing it first. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource). This combines the effects of the 1 0 4 7 and 1 0 4 8 modes. Use this with terminfo-based applications rather than the 4 7 mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 0 ? Set terminfo/termcap function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 1 ? Set Sun function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 2 ? Set HP function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 3 ? Set SCO function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 6 0 ? Set legacy keyboard emulation (X11R6).
            //P s = 1 0 6 1 ? Set VT220 keyboard emulation.
            //P s = 2 0 0 4 ? Set bracketed paste mode.
        case 'i':
            // Media Copy (MC).  (DEC-specific) ESC [ ? i
            //P s = 0 ? Print screen (default).
            //P s = 4 ? Turn off printer controller mode.
            //P s = 5 ? Turn on printer controller mode.

        case 'l':
            // Reset Mode (RM).
            //P s = 2 ? Keyboard Action Mode (AM).
            //P s = 4 ? Replace Mode (IRM).
            //P s = 1 2 ? Send/receive (SRM).
            //P s = 2 0 ? Normal Linefeed (LNM).

            // DEC Private Mode Reset (DECRST).
            //P s = 1 ? Normal Cursor Keys (DECCKM).
            //P s = 2 ? Designate VT52 mode (DECANM).
            //P s = 3 ? 80 Column Mode (DECCOLM).
            //P s = 4 ? Jump (Fast) Scroll (DECSCLM).
            //P s = 5 ? Normal Video (DECSCNM).
            //P s = 6 ? Normal Cursor Mode (DECOM).
            //P s = 7 ? No Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).
            //P s = 8 ? No Auto-repeat Keys (DECARM).
            //P s = 9 ? Don’t send Mouse X & Y on button press.
            //P s = 1 0 ? Hide toolbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 2 ? Stop Blinking Cursor (att610).
            //P s = 1 8 ? Don’t print form feed (DECPFF).
            //P s = 1 9 ? Limit print to scrolling region (DECPEX).
            //P s = 2 5 ? Hide Cursor (DECTCEM).
            //P s = 3 0 ? Don’t show scrollbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 3 5 ? Disable font-shifting functions (rxvt).
            //P s = 4 0 ? Disallow 80 ? 132 Mode.
            //P s = 4 1 ? No more(1) fix (see curses resource).
            //P s = 4 2 ? Disable National Replacement Character sets (DECNRCM).
            //P s = 4 4 ? Turn Off Margin Bell.
            //P s = 4 5 ? No Reverse-wraparound Mode.
            //P s = 4 6 ? Stop Logging. (This is normally disabled by a compile-time option).
            //P s = 4 7 ? Use Normal Screen Buffer.
            //P s = 6 6 ? Numeric keypad (DECNKM).
            //P s = 6 7 ? Backarrow key sends delete (DECBKM).
            //P s = 6 9 ? Disable left and right margin mode (DECLRMM), VT420 and up.
            //P s = 9 5 ? Clear screen when DECCOLM is set/reset (DECNCSM), VT510 and up.
            //P s = 1 0 0 0 ? Don’t send Mouse X & Y on button press and release. See the section Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 1 ? Don’t use Hilite Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 2 ? Don’t use Cell Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 3 ? Don’t use All Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 4 ? Don’t send FocusIn/FocusOut events.
            //P s = 1 0 0 5 ? Disable UTF-8 Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 6 ? Disable SGR Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 7 ? Disable Alternate Scroll Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 1 0 ? Don’t scroll to bottom on tty output (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 1 ? Don’t scroll to bottom on key press (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 5 ? Disable urxvt Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 3 4 ? Don’t interpret "meta" key. (This disables the eightBitInput resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 5 ? Disable special modifiers for Alt and NumLock keys. (This disables the numLock resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 6 ? Don’t send ESC when Meta modifies a key. (This disables the metaSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 7 ? Send VT220 Remove from the editing-keypad Delete key.
            //P s = 1 0 3 9 ? Don’t send ESC when Alt modifies a key. (This disables the altSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 0 ? Do not keep selection when not highlighted. (This disables the keepSelection resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 1 ? Use the PRIMARY selection. (This disables the selectToClipboard resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 2 ? Disable Urgency window manager hint when Control-G is received. (This disables the bellIsUrgent resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 3 ? Disable raising of the window when Control-G is received. (This disables the popOnBell resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 7 ? Use Normal Screen Buffer, clearing screen first if in the Alternate Screen. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 8 ? Restore cursor as in DECRC. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 9 ? Use Normal Screen Buffer and restore cursor as in DECRC. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource). This combines the effects of the 1 0 4 7 and 1 0 4 8 modes. Use this with terminfo-based applications rather than the 4 7 mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 0 ? Reset terminfo/termcap function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 1 ? Reset Sun function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 2 ? Reset HP function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 3 ? Reset SCO function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 6 0 ? Reset legacy keyboard emulation (X11R6).
            //P s = 1 0 6 1 ? Reset keyboard emulation to Sun/PC style.
            //P s = 2 0 0 4 ? Reset bracketed paste mode.
        case 'm':
            // Character Attributes (SGR).

            //P s = 0 ? Normal (default).
            //P s = 1 ? Bold.
            //P s = 2 ? Faint, decreased intensity (ISO 6429).
            //P s = 3 ? Italicized (ISO 6429).
            //P s = 4 ? Underlined.
            //P s = 5 ? Blink (appears as Bold).
            //P s = 7 ? Inverse.
            //P s = 8 ? Invisible, i.e., hidden (VT300).
            //P s = 9 ? Crossed-out characters (ISO 6429).
            //P s = 2 1 ? Doubly-underlined (ISO 6429).
            //P s = 2 2 ? Normal (neither bold nor faint).
            //P s = 2 3 ? Not italicized (ISO 6429).
            //P s = 2 4 ? Not underlined.
            //P s = 2 5 ? Steady (not blinking).
            //P s = 2 7 ? Positive (not inverse).
            //P s = 2 8 ? Visible, i.e., not hidden (VT300).
            //P s = 2 9 ? Not crossed-out (ISO 6429).
            //P s = 3 0 ? Set foreground color to Black.
            //P s = 3 1 ? Set foreground color to Red.
            //P s = 3 2 ? Set foreground color to Green.
            //P s = 3 3 ? Set foreground color to Yellow.
            //P s = 3 4 ? Set foreground color to Blue.
            //P s = 3 5 ? Set foreground color to Magenta.
            //P s = 3 6 ? Set foreground color to Cyan.
            //P s = 3 7 ? Set foreground color to White.
            //P s = 3 9 ? Set foreground color to default (original).
            //P s = 4 0 ? Set background color to Black.
            //P s = 4 1 ? Set background color to Red.
            //P s = 4 2 ? Set background color to Green.
            //P s = 4 3 ? Set background color to Yellow.
            //P s = 4 4 ? Set background color to Blue.
            //P s = 4 5 ? Set background color to Magenta.
            //P s = 4 6 ? Set background color to Cyan.
            //P s = 4 7 ? Set background color to White.
            //P s = 4 9 ? Set background color to default (original).

            // If 16-color support is compiled, the following apply. Assume that xterm’s resources are set so that the ISO color codes are the first 8 of a set of 16.
            // Then the aixterm colors are the bright versions of the ISO colors:
            //P s = 9 0 ? Set foreground color to Black.
            //P s = 9 1 ? Set foreground color to Red.
            //P s = 9 2 ? Set foreground color to Green.
            //P s = 9 3 ? Set foreground color to Yellow.
            //P s = 9 4 ? Set foreground color to Blue.
            //P s = 9 5 ? Set foreground color to Magenta.
            //P s = 9 6 ? Set foreground color to Cyan.
            //P s = 9 7 ? Set foreground color to White.
            //P s = 1 0 0 ? Set background color to Black.
            //P s = 1 0 1 ? Set background color to Red.
            //P s = 1 0 2 ? Set background color to Green.
            //P s = 1 0 3 ? Set background color to Yellow.
            //P s = 1 0 4 ? Set background color to Blue.
            //P s = 1 0 5 ? Set background color to Magenta.
            //P s = 1 0 6 ? Set background color to Cyan.
            //P s = 1 0 7 ? Set background color to White.

            // If xterm is compiled with the 16-color support disabled, it supports the following, from rxvt:
            //P s = 1 0 0 ? Set foreground and background color to default.
            // Xterm maintains a color palette whose entries are identified by an index beginning with zero. If 88- or 256-color support is compiled, the following apply:

            //All parameters are decimal integers.
            //RGB values range from zero (0) to 255.
            //ISO-8613-3 can be interpreted in more than one way; xterm allows the semicolons in this control to be replaced by colons (but after the first colon, colons must be used).

            // These ISO-8613-3 controls are supported:
            //P s = 3 8 ; 2 ; P r ; P g ; P b ? Set foreground color to the closest match in xterm’s palette for the given RGB P r /P g /P b .
            //P s = 3 8 ; 5 ; P s ? Set foreground color to the second P s .
            //P s = 4 8 ; 2 ; P r ; P g ; P b ? Set background color to the closest match in xterm’s palette for the given RGB P r /P g /P b .
            //P s = 4 8 ; 5 ; P s ? Set background color to the second P s .

        case 'n':
            // Device Status Report (DSR).
            //P s = 5 ? Status Report. Result (‘‘OK’’) is
            //CSI 0 n
            //P s = 6 ? Report Cursor Position (CPR) [row;column]. Result is
            //CSI r ; c R

            // Note: it is possible for this sequence to be sent by a function
            // key. For example, with the default keyboard configuration
            // the shifted F1 key may send (with shift-, control-, alt-modifiers)
            //CSI 1 ; 2 R , or
            //CSI 1 ; 5 R , or
            //CSI 1 ; 6 R , etc.

        case 'p':
        case 'q':
            // Load LEDs (DECLL).
            //P s = 0 ? Clear all LEDS (default).
            //P s = 1 ? Light Num Lock.
            //P s = 2 ? Light Caps Lock.
            //P s = 3 ? Light Scroll Lock.
            //P s = 2 1 ? Extinguish Num Lock.
            //P s = 2 2 ? Extinguish Caps Lock.
            //P s = 2 3 ? Extinguish Scroll Lock.

        case 'r':  // Set Scrolling Region [top;bottom] (default = full size of window) (DECSTBM).
        case 's':  // Save cursor position (ANSI.SYS), available only when DECLRMM is disabled.
        case 't':  // Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions).

        case 'u': // Restore cursor position (ANSI.SYS).
        case 'x':
            // Request Terminal Parameters (DECREQTPARM).
            // if P s is a "0" (default) or "1", and xterm is emulating VT100,
            // the control sequence elicits a response of the same form whose
            // parameters describe the terminal:
            //P s ? the given P s incremented by 2.
            //P n = 1 ? no parity.
            //P n = 1 ? eight bits.
            //P n = 1 ? 2 8 transmit 38.4k baud.
            //P n = 1 ? 2 8 receive 38.4k baud.
            //P n = 1 ? clock multiplier.
            //P n = 0 ? STP flags.
        case '!':  // Soft terminal reset (DECSTR).
            // Valid Sequences Ended.
            m_is_sequence_completed = true;
            break;

            // Unsupported Text and Keyboard Modifiers.
            // These are Preceding Modifiers ie after ESC [ >
        case '>':
        case '$':
        case '"':
        case '*':
            m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
            break;

        case '?': // -- Switch to next sequenceLevel
            // Ie.. handle ESC[?7h, ESC[?7l, and other ? DEC Sequences.
            // These Sequences DEC Level Sequences and need extra Parsing.
        case ' ': // Need to Precheck SyncTerm Font switching ' D' Space D.
            ++m_sequence_level;
            break;
        default:
            // Nothing Matched, Shouldn't get here.
            m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Level 2 Parsing Catches (2) Different Sequence Styles and Comes After ESC[ = CSI.
 * Specifically for ? preceding sequencing, and ' ' Space D ending Sequence
 * For syncterm font switching.
 *
 * Numbers and Separators are found in the middle of sequences as Parameters
 * Switch Statement catch the end of a Valid Sequence.
 *
 * Any non-supported sequences can have certain characters after the CSI
 * and These are parsed so that they are skipped and marked Invalid.
 */
void SequenceDecoder::processSequenceLevel2()
{
    // If the last addition to sequence is a space and we are now here.
    // The only valid terminator = 'D' for Sycnterm Font Switching.
    if(m_sequence_builder[m_sequence_builder.size()-2] == ' ' && m_sequence != 'D')
    {
        m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
        return;
    }

    // If we get here, only valid Sequences are ESC [ Then next Character.
    // First Check for Parameters in Sequence
    if(std::isdigit(m_sequence))  // Mark for Parameter
    {
        // Continue to next sequence
        return;
    }
    else if(m_sequence == ';') // Mark for Multi-Parameter
    {
        // Continue to Next Sequence
        return;
    }

    // Catch Valid ESC Sequence Terminators.
    switch(m_sequence)
    {
        case 'D':
            // SyncTerm Font Switching Sequences
            // SyncTerm Sequences have a Space before the D,
            // If a space is found, the sequence is passed from the previous level.
            // ESC [0;0 D

            // First we are catching DEC Style ESC[? Parameters here.
        case 'J':
            // Erase in Display (ED). - DECSED has ESC[?J
            //P s = 0 ? Erase Below (default).
            //P s = 1 ? Erase Above.
            //P s = 2 ? Erase All.
        case 'K':
            // Erase in Line (EL). - DECSED has ESC[?K
            //P s = 0 ? Erase to Right (default).
            //P s = 1 ? Erase to Left.
            //P s = 2 ? Erase All.
        case 'h':
            // DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET). ESC [ ? h
            //P s = 1 ? Application Cursor Keys (DECCKM).
            //P s = 2 ? Designate USASCII for character sets G0-G3 (DECANM), and set VT100 mode.
            //P s = 3 ? 132 Column Mode (DECCOLM).
            //P s = 4 ? Smooth (Slow) Scroll (DECSCLM).
            //P s = 5 ? Reverse Video (DECSCNM).
            //P s = 6 ? Origin Mode (DECOM).
            //P s = 7 ? Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).
            //P s = 8 ? Auto-repeat Keys (DECARM).
            //P s = 9 ? Send Mouse X & Y on button press. See the section Mouse Tracking. This is the X10 xterm mouse protocol.
            //P s = 1 0 ? Show toolbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 2 ? Start Blinking Cursor (att610).
            //P s = 1 8 ? Print form feed (DECPFF).
            //P s = 1 9 ? Set print extent to full screen (DECPEX).
            //P s = 2 5 ? Show Cursor (DECTCEM).
            //P s = 3 0 ? Show scrollbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 3 5 ? Enable font-shifting functions (rxvt).
            //P s = 3 8 ? Enter Tektronix Mode (DECTEK).
            //P s = 4 0 ? Allow 80 ? 132 Mode.
            //P s = 4 1 ? more(1) fix (see curses resource).
            //P s = 4 2 ? Enable National Replacement Character sets (DECNRCM).
            //P s = 4 4 ? Turn On Margin Bell.
            //P s = 4 5 ? Reverse-wraparound Mode.
            //P s = 4 6 ? Start Logging. This is normally disabled by a compile-time option.
            //P s = 4 7 ? Use Alternate Screen Buffer. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 6 6 ? Application keypad (DECNKM).
            //P s = 6 7 ? Backarrow key sends backspace (DECBKM).
            //P s = 6 9 ? Enable left and right margin mode (DECLRMM), VT420 and up.
            //P s = 9 5 ? Do not clear screen when DECCOLM is set/reset (DECNCSM), VT510 and up.
            //P s = 1 0 0 0 ? Send Mouse X & Y on button press and release. See the section Mouse Tracking. This is the X11 xterm mouse protocol.
            //P s = 1 0 0 1 ? Use Hilite Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 2 ? Use Cell Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 3 ? Use All Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 4 ? Send FocusIn/FocusOut events.
            //P s = 1 0 0 5 ? Enable UTF-8 Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 6 ? Enable SGR Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 7 ? Enable Alternate Scroll Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 1 0 ? Scroll to bottom on tty output (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 1 ? Scroll to bottom on key press (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 5 ? Enable urxvt Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 3 4 ? Interpret "meta" key, sets eighth bit. (enables the eightBitInput resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 5 ? Enable special modifiers for Alt and NumLock keys. (This enables the numLock resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 6 ? Send ESC when Meta modifies a key. (This enables the metaSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 7 ? Send DEL from the editing-keypad Delete key.
            //P s = 1 0 3 9 ? Send ESC when Alt modifies a key. (This enables the altSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 0 ? Keep selection even if not highlighted. (This enables the keepSelection resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 1 ? Use the CLIPBOARD selection. (This enables the selectToClipboard resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 2 ? Enable Urgency window manager hint when Control-G is received. (This enables the bellIsUrgent resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 3 ? Enable raising of the window when Control-G is received. (enables the popOnBell resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 7 ? Use Alternate Screen Buffer. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 8 ? Save cursor as in DECSC. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 9 ? Save cursor as in DECSC and use Alternate Screen Buffer, clearing it first. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource). This combines the effects of the 1 0 4 7 and 1 0 4 8 modes. Use this with terminfo-based applications rather than the 4 7 mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 0 ? Set terminfo/termcap function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 1 ? Set Sun function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 2 ? Set HP function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 3 ? Set SCO function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 6 0 ? Set legacy keyboard emulation (X11R6).
            //P s = 1 0 6 1 ? Set VT220 keyboard emulation.
            //P s = 2 0 0 4 ? Set bracketed paste mode.
        case 'i':
            // Media Copy (MC, DEC-specific).
            //P s = 1 ? Print line containing cursor.
            //P s = 4 ? Turn off autoprint mode.
            //P s = 5 ? Turn on autoprint mode.
            //P s = 1 0 ? Print composed display, ignores DECPEX.
            //P s = 1 1 ? Print all pages.

        case 'l':
            // DEC Private Mode Reset (DECRST).
            //P s = 1 ? Normal Cursor Keys (DECCKM).
            //P s = 2 ? Designate VT52 mode (DECANM).
            //P s = 3 ? 80 Column Mode (DECCOLM).
            //P s = 4 ? Jump (Fast) Scroll (DECSCLM).
            //P s = 5 ? Normal Video (DECSCNM).
            //P s = 6 ? Normal Cursor Mode (DECOM).
            //P s = 7 ? No Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).
            //P s = 8 ? No Auto-repeat Keys (DECARM).
            //P s = 9 ? Don’t send Mouse X & Y on button press.
            //P s = 1 0 ? Hide toolbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 2 ? Stop Blinking Cursor (att610).
            //P s = 1 8 ? Don’t print form feed (DECPFF).
            //P s = 1 9 ? Limit print to scrolling region (DECPEX).
            //P s = 2 5 ? Hide Cursor (DECTCEM).
            //P s = 3 0 ? Don’t show scrollbar (rxvt).
            //P s = 3 5 ? Disable font-shifting functions (rxvt).
            //P s = 4 0 ? Disallow 80 ? 132 Mode.
            //P s = 4 1 ? No more(1) fix (see curses resource).
            //P s = 4 2 ? Disable National Replacement Character sets (DECNRCM).
            //P s = 4 4 ? Turn Off Margin Bell.
            //P s = 4 5 ? No Reverse-wraparound Mode.
            //P s = 4 6 ? Stop Logging. (This is normally disabled by a compile-time option).
            //P s = 4 7 ? Use Normal Screen Buffer.
            //P s = 6 6 ? Numeric keypad (DECNKM).
            //P s = 6 7 ? Backarrow key sends delete (DECBKM).
            //P s = 6 9 ? Disable left and right margin mode (DECLRMM), VT420 and up.
            //P s = 9 5 ? Clear screen when DECCOLM is set/reset (DECNCSM), VT510 and up.
            //P s = 1 0 0 0 ? Don’t send Mouse X & Y on button press and release. See the section Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 1 ? Don’t use Hilite Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 2 ? Don’t use Cell Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 3 ? Don’t use All Motion Mouse Tracking.
            //P s = 1 0 0 4 ? Don’t send FocusIn/FocusOut events.
            //P s = 1 0 0 5 ? Disable UTF-8 Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 6 ? Disable SGR Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 0 7 ? Disable Alternate Scroll Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 1 0 ? Don’t scroll to bottom on tty output (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 1 ? Don’t scroll to bottom on key press (rxvt).
            //P s = 1 0 1 5 ? Disable urxvt Mouse Mode.
            //P s = 1 0 3 4 ? Don’t interpret "meta" key. (This disables the eightBitInput resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 5 ? Disable special modifiers for Alt and NumLock keys. (This disables the numLock resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 6 ? Don’t send ESC when Meta modifies a key. (This disables the metaSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 3 7 ? Send VT220 Remove from the editing-keypad Delete key.
            //P s = 1 0 3 9 ? Don’t send ESC when Alt modifies a key. (This disables the altSendsEscape resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 0 ? Do not keep selection when not highlighted. (This disables the keepSelection resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 1 ? Use the PRIMARY selection. (This disables the selectToClipboard resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 2 ? Disable Urgency window manager hint when Control-G is received. (This disables the bellIsUrgent resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 3 ? Disable raising of the window when Control-G is received. (This disables the popOnBell resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 7 ? Use Normal Screen Buffer, clearing screen first if in the Alternate Screen. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 8 ? Restore cursor as in DECRC. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource).
            //P s = 1 0 4 9 ? Use Normal Screen Buffer and restore cursor as in DECRC. (This may be disabled by the titeInhibit resource). This combines the effects of the 1 0 4 7 and 1 0 4 8 modes. Use this with terminfo-based applications rather than the 4 7 mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 0 ? Reset terminfo/termcap function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 1 ? Reset Sun function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 2 ? Reset HP function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 5 3 ? Reset SCO function-key mode.
            //P s = 1 0 6 0 ? Reset legacy keyboard emulation (X11R6).
            //P s = 1 0 6 1 ? Reset keyboard emulation to Sun/PC style.
            //P s = 2 0 0 4 ? Reset bracketed paste mode.

        case 'n':
            // Device Status Report (DSR, DEC-specific).
            //P s = 6 ? Report Cursor Position (DECXCPR) [row;column] as CSI ? r ; c R (assumes the default page, i.e., "1").
            //P s = 1 5 ? Report Printer status as CSI ? 1 0 n (ready). or CSI ? 1 1 n (not ready).
            //P s = 2 5 ? Report UDK status as CSI ? 2 0 n (unlocked) or CSI ? 2 1 n (locked).
            //P s = 2 6 ? Report Keyboard status as
            //CSI ? 2 7 ; 1 ; 0 ; 0 n (North American).
            //The last two parameters apply to VT400 & up, and denote keyboard ready and LK01 respectively.
            //P s = 5 3 ? Report Locator status as CSI ? 5 3 n Locator available, if compiled-in, or CSI ? 5 0 n No Locator, if not.
            //P s = 5 5 ? Report Locator status as CSI ? 5 3 n Locator available, if compiled-in, or CSI ? 5 0 n No Locator, if not.
            //P s = 5 6 ? Report Locator type as CSI ? 5 7 ; 1 n Mouse, if compiled-in, or CSI ? 5 7 ; 0 n Cannot identify, if not.
            //P s = 6 2 ? Report macro space (DECMSR) as CSI P n \* {
            //P s = 6 3 ? Report memory checksum (DECCKSR) as DCS P t ! x x x x ST
            //P t is the request id (from an optional parameter to the request).
            //The x’s are hexadecimal digits 0-9 and A-F.
            //P s = 7 5 ? Report data integrity as CSI ? 7 0 n (ready, no errors)
            //P s = 8 5 ? Report multi-session configuration as CSI ? 8 3 n (not configured for multiple-session operation).

        case 'p':
        case 'q':
            // Load LEDs (DECLL).
            //P s = 0 ? Clear all LEDS (default).
            //P s = 1 ? Light Num Lock.
            //P s = 2 ? Light Caps Lock.
            //P s = 3 ? Light Scroll Lock.
            //P s = 2 1 ? Extinguish Num Lock.
            //P s = 2 2 ? Extinguish Caps Lock.
            //P s = 2 3 ? Extinguish Scroll Lock.

        case 'r':  // Restore DEC Private Mode Values. The value of P s previously saved is restored. P s values are the same as for DECSET.
        case 's':  // Save DEC Private Mode Values. P s values are the same as for DECSET.
        case '!':  // Soft terminal reset (DECSTR).
            // Valid Sequences Ended.
            m_is_sequence_completed = true;
            break;

            // Unsupported Text and Keyboard Modifiers.
            // These are Preceding Modifiers ie after ESC [ >
        case '>':
        case '$':
        case '"':
        case '*':
        case ' ':
            m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
            break;

        default:
            // Nothing Matched, Shouldn't get here.
            m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Decode and Validate Escapce Sequences.
 */
void SequenceDecoder::validateSequence()
{
    // Check and clear vector for fresh sequence
    // We only Validate on complete sequences, so we can clear here
    // to make sure each run.
    if(m_sequence_params.size() > 0)
        std::vector<int>().swap(m_sequence_params);

    // If we get there, we have full CSI with possible ; ; separators.
    try
    {
        // Remove ESC [ then get Terminator
        m_sequence_builder.erase(0,2);
        int sequenceTerminator =
            m_sequence_builder[m_sequence_builder.size()-1];

        // First Parameter is always the Sequence Terminator.
        m_sequence_params.push_back(sequenceTerminator);

        // Remove Sequence Terminator from string to text for parameters.
        m_sequence_builder.erase(m_sequence_builder.size()-1,1);
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception removing ESC and Terminator Sequences: "
                  << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // Split String by ';' character to separate parameters if it exists.
    if(m_sequence_builder.empty())
    {
        // We have no parameters, just terminator for single sequence.
        return;
    }

    // If we have a parameter separator, then tokenize the parameters.
    std::string::size_type result = m_sequence_builder.find(";",0);
    if(result != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::istringstream inStream(m_sequence_builder);
        std::istringstream tokenStream;
        std::string token;

        // 0;33;47 Splits 0 33 47
        // ignores spaces.
        while(std::getline(inStream, token, ';'))
        {
            tokenStream.clear();
            if(token.size() == 0)
            {
                token = "-1"; // Empty fields are set to -1 for implied parms.
            }
            tokenStream.str(token);                   // Token to Stream
            if((tokenStream >> m_parameter).fail())   // String to Int
            {
                // Skip this character.
                std::cout << "Exception String to Int Parameter Failure."
                          << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            m_sequence_params.push_back(m_parameter); // Add to Parameters Vector.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // First check for ? DEC Sequence Starter
        if(m_sequence_builder[0] == '?')
        {
            try
            {
                m_sequence_params.push_back('?');  // Add to Parameters Vector.
                m_sequence_builder.erase(0,1);     // Remove ?
            }
            catch(std::exception &e)
            {
                std::cout << "Exception removing ? sequence starter: "
                          << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        // No separator, translate the 1-3 digit code that should be present.
        std::istringstream tokenStream;
        tokenStream.str(m_sequence_builder);        // String to Stream
        if((tokenStream >> m_parameter).fail())     // String to Int
        {
            // Skip this character.
            std::cout << "Exception String to Int Parameter Failure."
                      << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            m_sequence_params.push_back(m_parameter); // Add to Parameters Vector.
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Queue the Pasred Data back to the Session for Display
 * @return
 */
bool SequenceDecoder::sessionQueue()
{
    // Handle to Session Instance
    session_ptr session = m_weak_session.lock();
    if(session)
    {
        session->m_data_queue.enqueue(m_message_queue);
        m_message_queue.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
/*
 * Takes String input and parses for ESC Control Sequences
 * State machine stays actives waiting for complete control sequences
 * before pushing any actions forwards.  Normal Text data is passed through.
 */
void SequenceDecoder::decodeEscSequenceData(std::string &input_string)
{
    // Clear Queue out for each run.
    m_message_queue.clear();

    //Parse entire string and remove any double ESC Sequences.
    std::string::size_type result = 0;
    while(result != std::string::npos)
    {
        result = input_string.find("\x1b\x1b");
        if(result != std::string::npos)
        {
            try
            {
                //input_string.replace(result,1,"^");
                // Pass through, remove double ESC!
                input_string.replace(result,1,"");
            }
            catch(std::exception &e)
            {
                std::cout << "Exception replacing double ESC characters: "
                          << e.what() << std::endl;
                m_sequence_state = SEQ_ERROR; // Reset The State
            }
        }
    }

    // Now loop entire string and find valid escape sequences.
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < input_string.size(); i++)
    {
        // Get next Input Sequence
        m_sequence = input_string[i];

        // Remove Bell from displaying. Annoying in Shell!
        // When not displaying, we'll push this to console so it beeps!
        if(m_sequence == '\x07')
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Check for Start of Sequence, if we hit a sequence we then need
        // To send all Valid Output that Proceeds this sequence so everything
        // is FIFO with regards to how incoming data is handled.
        if(m_sequence == '\x1b')
        {
            m_sequence_state = SEQ_START;
        }

        // Pre-Handle the Parser State
        switch(m_sequence_state)
        {
                // Normal Text Data, Append to Buffer
            case SEQ_NORMAL:
                m_valid_output_data += m_sequence;
                break;

                // Start of Sequence, Push ValidOutputData Buffer Through
                // Then switch to Processing State, So we have FIFO Data
                // Parsing.
            case SEQ_START:
                //TheAnsiParser::Instance()->textInput(validOutputData);
                // Build a Message Queue with PassThrough Text Data.
                {
                    m_message_queue.m_text = m_valid_output_data;

                    // Queue the Data back to the Session
                    if (!sessionQueue())
                        return;

                    m_valid_output_data.erase();
                    m_sequence_state = SEQ_PROCESSING;
                    m_sequence_builder += m_sequence;
                }
                break;

            case SEQ_PROCESSING:
                // Were in the middle of processing a control sequence
                // Keep is going till we get DONE!
                m_sequence_builder += m_sequence;
                break;

            case SEQ_ERROR:
                // Validating the Sequence Bombed, Clear the vector and continue.
                std::vector<int>().swap(m_sequence_params); // Clear for next run.
                m_sequence_builder.erase();                 // Clear Any Prebuilt.
                m_sequence_state = SEQ_NORMAL;
                continue;
        }

        if(m_sequence == '\x1b' && !m_is_sequence_completed)
        {
            // Error Checking, If were in the middle of an incomplete sequence
            // Then we shouldn't get an ESC before we complete the sequence!
            if(m_is_sequence)
            {
            m_escape_position = i;
            m_is_sequence = true;
            continue;
        }

        // Each Level is the next character after the ESC
        // Check the first few levels to make sure we have a valid CSI
        if(m_is_sequence && !m_is_invalid_sequence)
        {
            switch(m_sequence_level)
            {
                case 0: // Process first char after ESC '['
                    processSequenceLevel0();
                    // Move to next Level if valid.
                    if(!m_is_invalid_sequence)
                    {
                        ++m_sequence_level;
                    }
                    break;

                case 1: // Process second char after ESC [ 'c'
                    processSequenceLevel1();
                    break;

                case 2: // Process 2nd char after ESC [ '?' DEC Sequences
                    processSequenceLevel2();
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Handle Completed Control Sequences
        if(m_is_sequence_completed)
        {
            // Copy just this sequence into string for validation
            try
            {
                //escapeSequence =
                //    input_string.substr(escapePosition,(i+1)-escapePosition);

                // Break up the sequence into separate parameters for
                // The Screen Parser.
                validateSequence();
                m_sequence_state = SEQ_DONE;
            }
            catch(std::exception &e)
            {
                std::cout << "Exception substring on escapeSequence: "
                          << e.what() << std::endl;
                m_sequence_state = SEQ_ERROR;
            }

            // If the sequence is completed, The Parse the parameters and
            // Setup for ANSI Parser and Drawing to Screen.
            m_is_sequence_completed = false;
            m_is_sequence           = false;
            m_is_invalid_sequence   = false;
            m_sequence_level        = 0;
        }
        // Invalid Sequences, Replace ESC with ^ characters for display
        // Then move on.
        if(m_is_invalid_sequence)
        {
            for (unsigned char c : m_sequence_builder)
            {
                std::cout << "*** Invalid ESC SeqBuilder[0]: [" << int(c) << "]" << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << "*** Invalid ESC Seq: [" << m_sequence << "]" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "*** Invalid ESC Seq Level: [" << m_sequence_level << "]" << std::endl;

            m_is_sequence   = false;
            m_is_invalid_sequence = false;
            m_sequence_level   = 0;

            // First grab the entire sequence parsed so far, from ESC position
            // Place it into validOutputData to display on the screen,
            // We don't want To reset the loop because it will increment,
            // so we grab all characters parsed so far.
            try
            {
                m_valid_output_data += m_sequence_builder;
                m_sequence_builder.erase();
            }
            catch(std::exception &e)
            {
                std::cout << "Exception substring on ESC Position: "
                          << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
            // Reset the State
            m_sequence_state = SEQ_ERROR;
        }

        // Post-Handle the Parser State
        switch(m_sequence_state)
        {
            case SEQ_NORMAL:
                // If we are reset to this state, reset the level
                break;

            case SEQ_PROCESSING:
                // Were in the middle of processing a control sequence
                // Keep is going till we get DONE!
                break;

            case SEQ_DONE:
                // We hit an entire sequence, pass the vector
                /*
                 * Build Message Queue Broken Down Sequences
                 */
                {
                    m_message_queue.m_queueParams.swap(m_sequence_params);

                    // Queue the Data back to the Session
                    if (!sessionQueue())
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    std::vector<int>().swap(m_sequence_params); // Clear for next run.
                    m_sequence_state = SEQ_NORMAL; // Reset The State
                    m_sequence_builder.erase();
                }
                break;

            case SEQ_ERROR:
                // Validating the Sequence Bombed, Clear the vector and continue.
                std::vector<int>().swap(m_sequence_params); // Clear for next run.
                m_sequence_state = SEQ_NORMAL; // Reset The State
                m_sequence_builder.erase();
                break;
        }
    }

    // Catch any echo'ed input that passed through with no sequences
    if(m_sequence_state == SEQ_NORMAL && m_valid_output_data.size() > 0)
    {
        /*
         * Build Queue with Passthrough Message Test
         */
        m_message_queue.m_text = m_valid_output_data;

        // Queue the Data back to the Session
        if (!sessionQueue())
        {
            return;
        }
        m_valid_output_data.erase();
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Reset the Sequence Parser to refresh the screen
 */
void SequenceDecoder::resetParser()
{
    // Handle to Session Instatnce
    session_ptr session = m_weak_session.lock();
    if(session)
    {
        session->m_sequence_parser->reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent first question. Welcome to Code Review! And nice escample. =)

Comment: Would you mind telling us what standard or reference document you used for developing this code?

Comment: Sure, I followed the following URL for a complete list of Xterm Control Sequences:  http://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html

Comment: There is already a library out there that has all the control sequences for all the different types of terminal `man termlib` You may want to use that to decode the control sequence for the current terminal (which you can find by query the environment variable `TERM`).

Comment: Loki, Thanks for your feed back, but I'm creating a cross-platform terminal and telnet application. Termlib wouldn't be valid in Windows.

Comment: @Mercyful: Its valid for windows terminals (It may surprise people to know windows has a terminal).

Comment: @Mercyful: Note When replying add the `@` before the name and the person will get notified about the comment.

Comment: If you don't want to act directly with `termlib` you can use [`ncurses`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) which allows terminal independent movement and drawing using termlib underneath for cross platform compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.  First, though, let me say that **the comments are excellent** and greatly ease understanding the code.  Keep that up!

### Simplify the parser

The parser uses large switch statements and multiple named level parsers to decode.  While the code is probably reasonably efficient (most of the bulk is comments), it does make things harder to read and maintain.  An alternative approach would be to move from a code-centric to a data-centric model.  In particular, if your compiler supports C++11, it seems that a [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) would be a good match.  If, for some reason, your compiler does not support such constructs, you could build your own [trie structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Another option would be to re-examine the various `switch` statements.  For example, the 354-line `processSequenceLevel1()` function could be replaced with this equivalent code:

```
void SequenceDecoder::processSequenceLevel1()
{
    static const std::string valid{"@ABCDEFGHIJKLMPSTXZ`abcdefghilmnpqrstux!"};
    static const std::string nextlevel("? "};
    if(m_sequence == ';' || std::isdigit(m_sequence)) {
        return;
    }
    if (std::string::npos != valid.find(m_sequence) {
        m_is_sequence_completed = true;
    } else if (std::string::npos != nextlevel.find(m_sequence) {
        ++m_sequence_level;
    } else {
        m_is_invalid_sequence = true;
    }
}
```

### Reduce the scope of variables

There are a number of member variables that do not really need to exist.  For example, `m_is_sequence` could instead be a local variable within `decodeEscSequenceData` instead of a member value.  This makes the object less complex and the code easier to understand and maintain.

### Remember to `unlock` resources

We don't have the code for `session.hpp` but in several points in the code we see code like this:

```
session_ptr session = m_weak_session.lock();
```

However, there does not appear to be a matching `unlock()` call anywhere.  Unless this is implicitly handled by the `session` object, that could be a problem.

Comment: Thank for the feed-back it's been very helpful.   A note on the lock, boost::weak_ptr pointers automatically unlock and expire as soon as they leave scope.  There is no unlock for them but it's best to keep them in small area scopes outside of loops unless encapsulated.

Comment: Agree with making the parser simpler. If you use flex you will get a much more efficient parser generated for you. Also the code will be easier to read and verify it is correct.